# Fixed width for website

Tags: html, css

I have been doing some research about what width you should use for your website if you're not using responsive design.

The most mentioned width where:

**960px
978px
980px**

My question is since most of these posts where outdated, which one is prefered nowdays? 
I want it to scale down so good as possible for mobile devices.

Thanks Jack

Comment: 960px is still too wide for most of mobile devices...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 960 is divisible with *pretty much anything* (28 factors, which is **a lot**), that's the reason it's used the most. This not only scales well, but allows you to divide the page into many, many variants of equal-width column numbers.

And it's probably to stay around as a standard for quite a while (until we get much larger/denser displays).

Mobiles nowadays have no trouble scaling whatever you give them, but it's your task to make sure it looks nice and readable when it's scaled down, even if you decide not to use 960.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will keep it in mind ;)